# Why does the output only produce the last line of the write() call?

Tags: python, string, loops, file, for-loop

My task is to open up a file that the user inputs and then output the grade for the student and the average scores for:

- Midterm 1
- Midterm 2,
- Final Exam

But every time I try to write the string into the output file, the file only takes in the last line of the list. At the same time, the `'\n'` character does not help. I am a little confused.

Here's my code:

```
sum = 0
sum3 = 0
sum2 = 0
n = []
# TODO: Read a file name from the user and read the tsv file here.
file = input()
with open(file) as f:
    data = f.readlines()

# TODO: Compute student grades and exam averages, then output results to a text file here.
with open('report.txt', 'w') as output:
    for line in data:
        split_line = line.split('\t')
        sum1 = int(split_line[2]) + int(split_line[3]) + int(split_line[4])
        avg = sum1 / 3
        # TODO: Compute student grades and exam averages, then output results to a text
        # file here.
        for i in data:
            if avg >= 90:
                split_line.append('A'+'\n')
            if 80 <= avg < 90:
                split_line.append('B'+'\n')
            if 70 <= avg < 80:
                split_line.append('C'+'\n')
            if  60 <= avg < 70:
                split_line.append('D'+'\n')
            if avg < 60:
                split_line.append('F'+'\n')
            break
        for j in data:
            sum += int(split_line[2])
            avg = sum/len(data)
            break
        for k in data:
            sum3 += int(split_line[3])
            avg1 = sum3/len(data)
            break
        for l in data:
            sum2 += int(split_line[4])
            avg2 = sum2/len(data)
            break
    for i in data:
        output.write(str(split_line))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need all those inner loops, which don't actually iterate.

You need to move the `output.write()` call into the loop, so you write each line after you determine it. Use `'\t'.join()` to make the output file a TSV.

Instead of the variables `sum`, `sum2`, `sum3`, you can use a list for all the sums. Then you can use a loop to add to them for each student.

```
subject_totals = [0, 0, 0]

with open('report.txt', 'w') as output:
    for line in data:
        split_line = line.strip().split('\t')
        grades = [int(i) for i in split_line[2:]]
        for i, grade in enumerate(grades):
            subject_totals[i] += grade
        avg = sum(grades) / len(grades)
        if avg >= 90:
            split_line.append('A')
        elif avg >= 80:
            split_line.append('B')
        elif avg >= 70:
            split_line.append('C')
        elif avg >= 60:
            split_line.append('D')
        else:
            split_line.append('F')
        output.write('\t'.join(split_line) + '\n')
        
subject_avgs = [total/len(data) for total in subject_totals]
```